# Como eliminar parte de un array desde una ventana hija, opener?

Tags: javascript, html, método, split

Soy nuevo en esto, no entiendo porque no funciona el método `pop` sobre una ventana padre, veo en la consola que se eliminan los elementos pero debería refrescarse la pagina no? No se como hacer esto.

Tengo varios `html` y `js` por lo que no puedo añadir todos, tengo una panel general que abre este `html`, que es un sorteo, si cliqueo sobre un botón puede haber premio o un terremoto, que elimina mis últimos dos edificios que están guardados en un array a medida que lo voy añadiendo... Intento ir a la ventana padre y sobre su objeto, hacer pop pero no va:

```
opener.objPartida.parque.pop()
```

Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
let price = Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length) + 1;
let earthquake = price;
let premioDinero = 10000;

if (opener === null) {
  alert('Pasa primero por el panel generl')
  location.assign("../index.html");
}

while(price == earthquake){
  earthquake = Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length) + 1;
}
console.log('Price is in button ' + price);
console.log('Earthquake is in button ' + earthquake);

let premioBoton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[price - 1];
let earthquakeBoton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[earthquake - 1];


for (button of buttons) {
  button.onclick = function(e){
    if (e.target === premioBoton) {
      alert('premio');
      opener.contadorSaldoActual = opener.objPartida.saldo += premioDinero;
    }
    if (e.target === earthquakeBoton) {
      alert('terremoto');
      let celdas = opener.document.getElementsByClassName('celda');
      let hija = opener.document;

        opener.objPartida.parque.pop();
        console.log(opener.objPartida.parque);
    }
  };
}






var objPartida = {
  iniciada: false,
  saldo: 3000,
  recaudacion: 0,
  visitantes: 0,
  detalles: {},
  parque: []
};

// Ejecución panel nueva partida
document.getElementById('nuevaPartida').onclick = function (){

  if (!objPartida.iniciada) {

    open("paneles/nuevapartida.html", 'Nueva partida', 'scrollbars=yes,width=700,height=1000,toolbar=yes');


  } else {

    msg('error', 'Ya has iniciado una partida previamente, no es posible crear una nueva partida');

  }
}

// Ejecución panel recaudar entradas
document.getElementById('recaudarCaja').onclick = function() {

  if (objPartida.iniciada) {

    open("paneles/recaudarEntradas.html", 'Recaudar Caja', 'scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=400');

  } else {

    msg('error', 'Para acceder al panel de recaudación, inicia una partida.');
  }
};

// Ejecución panel sorteo
document.getElementById('nuevoSorteo').onclick = function(){
  if (objPartida.iniciada) {
    if (objPartida.parque.length >= 2) {
      open("paneles/nuevoSorteo.html", 'width=600, height=500, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes');
    } else {
      msg('error', 'Debe tener al menos dos edificios para participar');
    }
  } else {
    msg('error', 'Para participar en el sorteo debe iniciar la partida');
  }
};

// Ejecución panel atracciones
let celdas = document.getElementsByClassName('celda');

for (cadaCelda of celdas) {

  cadaCelda.onclick = function() {

    let elemento = this.dataset;

    if (objPartida.iniciada) {

      if (elemento.edificio === "vacia") {

        let ventana = open("paneles/nuevoEdificio.html", 'Crear edificio', 'scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=800');

        ventana.onload = function() {

          ventana.document.getElementById('numeroCelda').textContent = elemento.celda;
        }

      } else {

        msg('error', 'Ya hay un edificio en esta celda.');
      }

    } else {

      msg('error', 'Para acceder al panel de construcción inicia una partida.');
    }
  }
}


// intervalo de actualización

let actualizador = setInterval( function(){

  if (objPartida.iniciada) {

    let parque = objPartida.parque;

    // progresion parque
    for (let edificio of parque) {
      console.log(edificio);
      if (edificio.tipo === "atraccion") {

        objPartida.visitantes += parseInt(edificio.visitantes);
        objPartida.recaudacion += parseInt(edificio.visitantes * 2);
      }

      if (edificio.tipo === "puesto") {

        objPartida.saldo += parseInt(edificio.ingresos);
      }
    }
    // actualizacion interfaz
    document.getElementById('contadorRecaudacion').textContent = objPartida.recaudacion + "$ en caja";
    document.getElementById('contadorSaldoActual').textContent = objPartida.saldo + "$";
    document.getElementById('contadorEdificios').textContent = parque.length + " edificios";
    document.getElementById('contadorVisitantes').textContent = objPartida.visitantes + " visitantes";
  }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<html lang="es">

 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sorteo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
 </head>

    <body class="panel sorteo">

     <h1>¡Bienvenido!</h1>

     <p>Realiza un sorteo cada hora y podrás ganar 10.000$... ¡o un terrible terremoto!</p>

     <h2>¿A qué número apuestas?</h2>
 
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>

  <div id="alerta"></div>

  <script src="../js/comun.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/nuevoSorteo.js"></script>
  
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de la ventana opener? Sería interesante saber el código necesario para poder reproducir el problema. Lee [ask] y [mcve] para más información.

Comment: añadí otro documento js en la misma hoja ya que no se como se suben dos archivos de js, ahi esta el panel general(la ventana padre) que tiene un objeto con un array parque al que le habia hecho push de mis edificios construidos(instancia de objeto), quiero desde el sorteo de botones, vaciar el array con pop pero no me va